# How to read child nodes in Firebase Realtime Database - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, crud

I have multiple child nodes in my Firebase Realtime Database, but I don't know ow to read to the child node.
[image: Database Child Nodes]

Code:

```
Query dbRefNode = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('Rides'); //maybe .child('Rides/childnode') but I don't know what to write because the child node is a randomly generated string

  _getDBRides() {
    return Expanded(
      child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
        query: dbRefNode,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
            Animation<double> animation, int index) {

          Map<dynamic, dynamic> Rides = {};
          if (snapshot.value is Map<dynamic, dynamic>) {
            Rides = snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
          }

          //unique key/id of each item in db
          Rides['key'] = snapshot.key;
          print(Rides['key']);

          return listItem(Rides: Rides);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Right now this code returns the USER (see image) when I print Rides['key']. BUT I don't want to retrieve the user, I want to retrieve the INFO (see image), so when I write in my code Rides['Color'] it returns null because it's looking for a Color in the user node and not in the info node, how can I fix this.

Thank you in advance if you end up helping me!

Comment: This is the third post about the same problem. Instead of reposting, please improve your original question based on the guidance given there.

Comment: I just thought to start fresh, please can you help me with my problem? If not then it's fine

Comment: I edited the original questions, hopefully someone can help, thx for the recommendations